# Unity + Android + Daydream, download video file and play in app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, daydream

I would like to download a video from a URL and play it in the unity /  Daydream app that I'm making for Android.

I'm not really sure where to save the downloaded video so the App can use it.

I can download the video to Android Application.persistentDataPath but it does not seem to work when I try and download the video to the StreamingAssets path.

I was under the impression that I need to read the video files from the StreamingAssets path?

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 1):

I got this to work successfully with a little modification to the Daydream video sample inside the Daydream Unity SDK. Inside the "ShowSample" function in SwitchVideo.cs, I replaced the code which loads a new video.

What I'm doing is:

1. Download video to something under Application.persistentDataPath.
2. Prepend `file://` to the file path. I believe this is necessary because you can also access files built into the jar using `jar:` and these would need to be unzipped. The one you download does not.
3. Set `GvrVideoPlayerTexture.videoURL` to this path.
4. In this case, `type` is set to `other`, and the content ID and provider ID are left empty.
5. Call `ReInitializeVideo`.

   ```
     var www = new WWW("https://archive.org/download/Pbtestfilemp4videotestmp4/video_test_512kb.mp4");
     var path = Application.persistentDataPath + "/a.mp4";

     while (!www.isDone) {
       print(www.progress);
     }
     File.WriteAllBytes(path, www.bytes);

     var video = videoSamples[i].GetComponentInChildren<GvrVideoPlayerTexture>();
     video.videoURL = "file://" + path;
     video.ReInitializeVideo();
   ```

Note that you can stream videos too. If you set `videoURL` to an http path, it should work, but I'm assuming you want something that can save the videos for offline use.